# How can I change all files prefixes in one command?

Tags: files, filename, rename

I need to change the postfixes of all files (all the same .JPEG) to .jpeg (Capital vs. lower case).
Is there a quick way of doing so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the Perl program `rename` which is installed by default:

```
rename 's/\.JPEG$/.jpeg/' *.JPEG
```

The first argument is a Perl regular expression matching filenames ending with `.JPEG` and replaces it with `.jpeg`.

The second argument selects the files that should be matched, in your case every file in the current directory ending on `.JPEG`. You could specify a different location of course:

```
rename 's/\.JPEG$/.jpeg/' ~/Pictures/*.JPEG
```

Other answers I've seen:

- `rename s/.JPEG$/.jpeg/ *` - this will also rename files like `StupidJPEG` to `Stupi.jpeg` because the dot is matches any character. `.JPEG$` is a regular expression
- `rename 's/\.JPEG$/\.jpeg/' *` - works, but it's less efficient because it passes all files in the current directory to `rename`.
- `rename -n 's/.JPEG$/.jpeg/' *.JPEG` - the `-n` option would show the files being renamed, without actually renaming them ("dry run"). Because `*.JPEG` matches files postfixed with `.JPEG` only, the dot-matches-all issue is non-existent here.

Comment: The second dot does not need to be escaped because it's not part of the matching expression. In a regular expression, `.` matches any character (with a few exceptions), therefore the dot needs to be escaped in the regular expression `\.JPEG$`.

Comment: This also works: `for i in *.JPEG; do mv $i $(basename $i .JPEG).jpeg; done`

Comment: @crazy2be: Make an answer of it. It's useful in case `rename` is not available. Also, `$(basename $i .JPEG)` can be replaced with `${i%%.JPEG}` (bash extension)

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool for this:

`sudo apt-get install renameutils` or click [renameutils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/renameutils)

(if not already installed)

where you can do (from command line):

`rename s/\.JPEG$/\.jpeg/ *.JPEG`

Answer (score 3):

Although this is possibly not the best solution for this particular usage case,

```
for i in *.JPEG; do mv "$i" "$(basename "$i" .JPEG).jpeg"; done
```

also works. We can do some trickyness with bash in order to slightly increase efficiency (avoiding in invocation of an additional sub-process in the inner loop), ending up with:

```
for i in *.JPEG; do mv "$i" "${i%%.JPEG}.jpeg"; done
```

This solution is most useful if you want to do something else *in additon* to renaming the files, such as logging what names were changed, or even just doing a dry run to ensure that it does what you want.

Comment: I recommend putting the variables between double quotes, it's not uncommon for images to have spaces in their names.

Comment: Done! I forgot about that, it worked in my test (files named 1-1000.JPEG sequentially) :P.

Answer (score 2):

Found it a second after posting:

```
rename 's/\.JPEG$/.jpeg/' *
```

Comment: A small optimization, but for a large amount of files, my answer (and tgm's answer) are preferred because it sends less files to `rename` for parsing. `*` matches everything in a directory where `*.JPEG` would really match just the files postfixed with `.JPEG`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rename command. It's different than move and often is causes confusion because it was specifically created with picture renaming in mind.

Something like this command should work (for all files that end in .JPEG, change .JPEG to .jpeg)

rename -n 's/.JPEG$/.jpeg/' *.JPEG

Answer (score 1):

Doing things in [*parallel*](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)  is getting more and more important, hence I recommend:

```
parallel mv {} {.}.jpg ::: *.JPG
```

This utility is not installed by default though.

Comment: Nice to know about this, but I really need something quick and Dirty, and do not really care for performance/efficiency

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a nice GUI solution and don't want to muck about with complicated command line arguments, there is a great **Nautilus script** available to rename files. It has a simple interface and many options.

Available here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Renamer?content=87601